# Logging with SpecRun.Specflow and xUnit(ITestOutputHelper) - BoDi.ObjectContainerException

Tags: c#, xunit, specflow

I'm trying to add logs to specflow tests but unfortunetly I got exception. I'm using `SpecRun.Specflow v3.4.19` library with `xunit`. While trying to inject `ITestOutputHelper` via Context Injection I got this:

> Interface cannot be resolved: Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper (resolution path: SpecflowTesting.Steps.CalculatorStepDefinitions)
> Stack Trace:
> BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Interface cannot be resolved: Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper (resolution path: SpecflowTesting.Steps.CalculatorStepDefinitions)
> TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
> ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
> ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
> <>c__DisplayClass57_0.b__0(ParameterInfo p)
> SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray() Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> ObjectContainer.ResolveArguments(IEnumerable`1 parameters, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
> ObjectContainer.CreateObject(Type type, ResolutionList resolutionPath, RegistrationKey keyToResolve)
> TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
> ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
> ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
> ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
> TestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer container) line 11
> lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Int32 )
> BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) line 69
> TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments) line 514
> RunnerTestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
> TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 435
> TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep() line 260
> RunnerTestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
> TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors() line 60
> CalculatorFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
> CalculatorFeature.AddTwoNumbers() line 8
> StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
> StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
> TestNodeTask.Execute()

Usage:

```
    private ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

    private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public CalculatorStepDefinitions(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the SpecRun.SpecFlow package you are using the SpecFlow+ Runner as unit test runner. You are NOT using xUnit and so you can't use the xUnit APIs to log stuff.

You have two options:

1. You stay with the SpecFlow+ Runner and use `ISpecFlowOutputHelper` interface to write your log entries
2. You change to the SpecFlow.xUnit package (and remove the SpecRun.SpecFlow package) to use xUnit as a unit test runner. Then you can still use the `ISpecFlowOutputHelper` interface or use the xUnit APIs directly.

---

Full disclosure: I am the Community Manager for SpecFlow and SpecFlow+